# Prevent same post value WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I need to stop inserting in the WordPress database a value if already exists. What I tried and I don't know why it's not working. I'm using the next code in functions.php and I have and ajax call. Can someone make some light on this please.

**My code**

```php
$i_can_add_value = true;
$error_reason = false;
    $published_values = $wpdb->get_results(
     "SELECT ID FROM ".$wpdb->posts." WHERE post_author = %d AND post_status IN ('draft','publish') AND post_type = 'custom' ", $current_user->ID
             );
    if (!empty($published_values)){
        foreach ($published_values as $id_already_published){
            $temp_custom = get_post_meta($id_already_published->ID, 'custom', true);
            if ($temp_custom === $description && $description !='') {
                    $i_can_add_value = false;
                    $error_reason = 'You already added that!';
            }
        }
    }
if($i_can_add_value){
        wp_insert_post($my_post);
    } else {
        echo "Error: ".$error_reason;
    }
```

Comment: did you try post_parent?

Comment: what do you mean by post_parent? what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to be sure that you code is working at all when ajax is called.

If this code is working then you need to check three conditions in your code.

1) `if (!empty($published_values)`

$published_values can be empty because of the incorrect sql query.

2) `$temp_custom`

Can also be empty. Check it.

3) `$description`

And this variable can be empty as well.